# html background custom color not cover the whole page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have this custom color cover the whole page but it's only covering part of it. I have the same issues with other pages which has a similar layout. I know that I need to move my styling to a CSS file but for now, I am just testing things out. I looked at other solutions but have not found the one that helped me yet. maybe cause I am using thymeleaf, not sure!!!!

[image]

**and here is my HTML code **

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="https://www.thymleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>VoiceIt App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<style>
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
}
#multi-color-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(firefox.png),
      url(bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgb(132, 208, 191), rgb(153, 132, 208));
  background-repeat: no-repeat,
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
  background-position: bottom right,
      left,
      right;
}
</style>

<body id="multi-color-bg">

    <!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/register}">Registration and
                    Login</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <h1>User Login Page</h1>
                <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">

                    <!-- error message -->
                    <div th:if="${param.error}">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or
                            password.</div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- logout message -->
                    <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                        <div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out.</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username"> Username </label> : <input type="text"
                            class="form-control" id="username" name="username"
                            placeholder="Enter Email ID" autofocus="autofocus">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>: <input type="password"
                            id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                            placeholder="Enter Password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                                    class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log In" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <span>New user? <a href="/" th:href="@{/register}">Register
                            here</a></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I copied your `HTML` and opened on my browser and everything seem look so fine. I think it might cause by your framework that you working on. It wasn't about this `HTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try to set the height `100%` and css `html { height: 100% }`

```css
html, body{
   height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to adjust the height of the body tag given in the custom **#multi-color-bg** id rules that you added to your HTML. Adding a 100% to it will do the trick, although I'd recommend to use a separated div as a wrapper for all the content of the body and leave the body apart with only the rule of 100vh to the body tag. This is of course optional, just an extra suggestion, pal.

```css
      .navbar {
      background-color: black;
      }
      #multi-color-bg {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-image: url(firefox.png),
      url(bubbles.png),
      linear-gradient(to right, rgb(132, 208, 191), rgb(153, 132, 208));
      background-repeat: no-repeat,
      no-repeat,
      no-repeat;
      background-position: bottom right,
      left,
      right;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="https://www.thymleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>VoiceIt App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <body id="multi-color-bg">
      <!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                  class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                  class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/register}">Registration and
               Login</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <h1>User Login Page</h1>
               <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                  <!-- error message -->
                  <div th:if="${param.error}">
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or
                        password.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- logout message -->
                  <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                     <div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out.</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="username"> Username </label> : <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="username" name="username"
                        placeholder="Enter Email ID" autofocus="autofocus">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="password">Password</label>: <input type="password"
                        id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Password" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                           <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                              class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log In" />
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <span>New user? <a href="/" th:href="@{/register}">Register
                  here</a></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting height to 100% is still not working try to set height to 100vh. And if it still not work add margin-top of required pixel.
I hope this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need to adjust the height of the body tag given in the custom **#multi-color-bg** id rules that you added to your HTML. **Adding a 100vh** to it will do the trick, although I'd recommend to use a separated div as a wrapper for all the content of the body and leave the body apart with only the rule of 100vh to the body tag. This is of course optional, just an extra suggestion, pal.

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: black;
}

#multi-color-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh !important;
    background-image: url(firefox.png),
        url(bubbles.png),
        linear-gradient(to right, rgb(132, 208, 191), rgb(153, 132, 208));
    background-repeat: no-repeat,
        no-repeat,
        no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom right,
        left,
        right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:sec="https://www.thymleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>VoiceIt App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet"
         href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <body id="multi-color-bg">
      <!-- create navigation bar ( header) -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                  class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span
                  class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" th:href="@{/register}">Registration and
               Login</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
               <h1>User Login Page</h1>
               <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
                  <!-- error message -->
                  <div th:if="${param.error}">
                     <div class="alert alert-danger">Invalid username or
                        password.
                     </div>
                  </div>
                  <!-- logout message -->
                  <div th:if="${param.logout}">
                     <div class="alert alert-info">You have been logged out.</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="username"> Username </label> : <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="username" name="username"
                        placeholder="Enter Email ID" autofocus="autofocus">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <label for="password">Password</label>: <input type="password"
                        id="password" name="password" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Password" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                     <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                           <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit"
                              class="form-control btn btn-primary" value="Log In" />
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </form>
               <div class="form-group">
                  <span>New user? <a href="/" th:href="@{/register}">Register
                  here</a></span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the height of `body` is not full page and the background is applied on body.
so you should keep `body` at least `100vh` high

```
body{
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```